# How to make images in specific layout responsive?

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-images

I am trying to create an image gallery in html css, using positioning such as left:0px;, but I am struggling to make the images responsive for different screen sizes whilst keeping the layout. How can I fix this?

```
.bezaimageposition{
position:absolute;
right:670px;
top:0px;
   }
```

[idea of positioning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oymup.jpg)

I have attached the code I am using for the layout as well as how its supposed to look. I have researched responsive web design but I struggled to find a good method for applying responsive design to the specific layout I have.

Comment: Welcome to SO, I recommend checking out [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: Why don't you use a CSS grid? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid